# Repeating value from previous row in data frame R untill mutation in other column

Tags: r, dataframe

I want to create a data frame that in a very basic way logs the available stock in time. The casus: In a production facility every X hours new products arrive, and every Y hours products are consumed. The question that needs to be answered is how much stock is in the system at any given time. The chosen approach is a very basic simulation.

My struggle is to create a dataframe that shows the stock level at any given time. The dataframe should look like this.

```
df <- data.frame(
  time  = seq(1,48, by = 1),
  input = c(rep(c(rep(0,11), rep(12, 1)),4)),
  consumption = c(rep(0,11), rep(c(rep(-3,1), rep(0,2)),12), c(-3)),
  stock =       c(rep(0,11), rep(c(9,9,9,6,6,6,3,3,3,0,0,0),3), 9))
```

The time column indicates a specific timeslot (hours), the input column shows the quantity of delivered products per timeslot, the consumption column shows the quantity of consumed products per timeslot and the stock column shows the available stock per timeslot.

The challenge is to have the stock column update with the changes in the input and consumption column. Essentially in the stock column, the value of the row should be identical to the previous row in the stock column. The exception to this is when there is a mutation in the input or consumption column (on the same row).

This way the stock will be specified for each timeslot specified in the time column. With that information a graph that shows the stock level mutations over time can be made.

Notes

- Less than 0 stock is not possible.
- When delivered the products can be consumed instantly but not more than 3 at once.
- In reality the input quantity of products, time between deliveries and consumption speed of products is highly variable . Therefor the column needs to update dynamically.

Solution thanks to barboulotte

```
library(dplyr)
df$stock.calc <- NA
df$stock.calc[1] <- df$input[1] + df$consumption[1]
while(is.na(sum(df$stock.calc))) df <- mutate(df, stock.calc = ifelse(is.na(stock.calc), 
                                                                                  ifelse(lag(stock.calc) + input + consumption <0,0,   lag(stock.calc) + input + consumption) , stock.calc))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I understand you want to calculate the stock variable from previous stock and current input and consumption.

If so you can do it with `data.table` or `dplyr`:

```
df <- data.frame(
  time  = seq(1,48, by = 1),
  input = c(rep(c(rep(0,11), rep(12, 1)),4)),
  consumption = c(rep(0,11), rep(c(rep(-3,1), rep(0,2)),12), c(-3)),
  stock =       c(rep(0,11), rep(c(9,9,9,6,6,6,3,3,3,0,0,0),3), 9))

library(data.table)
setDT(df)
df$stock.calc1 <- NA
df$stock.calc1[1] <- df$input[1] + df$consumption[1]
while(is.na(sum(df$stock.calc1))) df[, stock.calc1 := ifelse(is.na(stock.calc1), shift(stock.calc1) + input + consumption, stock.calc1)]
setDF(df)

library(dplyr)
df$stock.calc2 <- NA
df$stock.calc2[1] <- df$input[1] + df$consumption[1]
while(is.na(sum(df$stock.calc2))) df <- mutate(df, stock.calc2 = ifelse(is.na(stock.calc2), lag(stock.calc2) + input + consumption, stock.calc2))
df
#>    time input consumption stock stock.calc1 stock.calc2
#> 1     1     0           0     0           0           0
#> 2     2     0           0     0           0           0
#> 3     3     0           0     0           0           0
#> 4     4     0           0     0           0           0
#> 5     5     0           0     0           0           0
#> 6     6     0           0     0           0           0
#> 7     7     0           0     0           0           0
#> 8     8     0           0     0           0           0
#> 9     9     0           0     0           0           0
#> 10   10     0           0     0           0           0
#> 11   11     0           0     0           0           0
#> 12   12    12          -3     9           9           9
#> 13   13     0           0     9           9           9
#> 14   14     0           0     9           9           9
#> 15   15     0          -3     6           6           6
#> 16   16     0           0     6           6           6
#> 17   17     0           0     6           6           6
#> 18   18     0          -3     3           3           3
#> 19   19     0           0     3           3           3
#> 20   20     0           0     3           3           3
#> 21   21     0          -3     0           0           0
#> 22   22     0           0     0           0           0
#> 23   23     0           0     0           0           0
#> 24   24    12          -3     9           9           9
#> 25   25     0           0     9           9           9
#> 26   26     0           0     9           9           9
#> 27   27     0          -3     6           6           6
#> 28   28     0           0     6           6           6
#> 29   29     0           0     6           6           6
#> 30   30     0          -3     3           3           3
#> 31   31     0           0     3           3           3
#> 32   32     0           0     3           3           3
#> 33   33     0          -3     0           0           0
#> 34   34     0           0     0           0           0
#> 35   35     0           0     0           0           0
#> 36   36    12          -3     9           9           9
#> 37   37     0           0     9           9           9
#> 38   38     0           0     9           9           9
#> 39   39     0          -3     6           6           6
#> 40   40     0           0     6           6           6
#> 41   41     0           0     6           6           6
#> 42   42     0          -3     3           3           3
#> 43   43     0           0     3           3           3
#> 44   44     0           0     3           3           3
#> 45   45     0          -3     0           0           0
#> 46   46     0           0     0           0           0
#> 47   47     0           0     0           0           0
#> 48   48    12          -3     9           9           9

# Created on 2021-04-15 by the reprex package (v2.0.0)
```

Comment: Thank you barboulotte for your fast answer. your solution works great I've added a restriction for negative values and it operates perfectly.

Comment: What does this line of code do?  `df.sim$stock.calc[1] <- df.sim$input[1] + df.sim$consumption[1]`.   I would expect it to simply add the value of the input column with the consumption column but when running it i dont see any effect in the dataframe.  However trying to run  `while(is.na(sum(df$stock.calc2))) df <- mutate(df, stock.calc2 = ifelse(is.na(stock.calc2), lag(stock.calc2) + input + consumption, stock.calc2))` without the previous code doesnt work. Clearly it does something but i cant understand what.

Comment: The calculation uses previous stock and current input and consumption so you have to calculate first stock before looping. Look at `head(df)` after `df.sim$stock.calc[1] <- df.sim$input[1] + df.sim$consumption[1]`.